# How to play wav-sound in Flixel?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flixel

I'm unable to play wav sound with Flixel library. By the way I'm using Flashdevelop.

*Error: 'pick.wav' does not have a recognized extension, and a mimeType was not provided*

```
[Embed(source = "pick.wav")]
private var picksound:Class;
```

*Error: Unable to transcode pick.wav.*

Comment: I converted the wav to a mp3, and then loaded it in the same way. It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot embed a .wav, but you can import one into the Flash IDE and compile an .swc

After that  you can add the .swc to your project and then create an instance of your `Sound`

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the .wav to .mp3

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html